# What's the opposite of pop up?

Tags: word-request

I'm programming a modal window and it can be *popped up*. I can't think of a good word for the opposite state. Similarly, if the window can *pop up*, what should be call the act of retracting to the previous state?

I [googled](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/pop%20up) but found no antonyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is commonly called 'dismiss', e.g. by Apple in their [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss). Their term for 'pop up' in this case is [*'present'*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present).

Also, the simple 'close' works as well to convey the meaning, I guess.

Comment: Would you say that the term is appropriate for non-computer circumstances as well? *A friend popped up but I dismissed him.* Does it sound grammatically right? (Definitely not socially, of course.)

Comment: I wouldn't use that for a friend, but in more formal circumstances it's appropriate: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismiss

Comment: @KonradV - I would say the opposite of _popped up_ in the non-computer sense would be _went away_, as in: _A problem popped up, but then it went away_ (the same could be said of a friend).

Comment: If you're talking about a toaster or a pop-up toy (e.g. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073DDJPKD), you "depress" or "close" first, before it pops up.

"Close" or "Dismiss" is what you do to a pop-up window.   "Show" and "Hide" are verbs, "visible" and "hidden" are adjectives (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp), and dismiss is how you make something hidden. (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

Answer (score 4):

The term "pop-up" originally reflected the fact that these windows seem to appear  quickly out of nowhere when opened in response to some interaction; they are superimposed upon another window and are usually smaller than the underlying window and originally had drop-shadows which made them appear to float above it.

The act of dismissing them has always been called "closing" them. There is no specific antonym that conveys the idea of closing just as rapidly as they had appeared.